# Loading data from different models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, razor, controller

I am trying to create a view where data is being loaded into from different models. On one side, I have line items for an order that are loaded as IEnumerable, similar to what you would do for the standard Index,

I am then going with a new, partial view to get data from a different model. **All of that works**, however, I am having issues loading data from the database as well, which for some reason does not work. I am sure this is not a big thing, however, I am struggling with it for quite some time now.

Here's the controller that is supposed to handle this:

```
        model.ShippingAddressModel = new ShippingAddressesViewModel
        {
            ShippingAddressFirstName = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressFirstName).ToString(),

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to load a collection of `ShippingAddressFirstName` into a `ShippingAddressFirstName` which, I suppose, is intended for a name string.

```
ShippingAddressFirstName = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressFirstName).First()
```

will put the first name found into `ShippingAddressFirstName`